# clear backstack actions when return to activity

Tags: android, android-intent

In my main activity i have a signIn button when i click on, it's change background color of this button and takes me to SignIn activity.

```
// Button SignInActivity
    final Button signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

My problem is when i back to MainActivity i find SignIn button with colorAccent background.
Any solution to clear up the background color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

First find the default background of Button like this

```
Drawable d = button.getBackground();
```

if you need default background again use this

`button.setBackgroundDrawable(d);` in your `onResume()` method.

manage your code using these lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can override your 'onResume()' method where you will need to 'setbackgroundColor" of your button to the default color.

```
@Override
    public protected onResume(){
          signIn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `selector` and assign it to the button in xml. For example:-

Create a file called `button_background.xml` inside drawable folder and copy paste the selector code below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="@color/buttonBackgroundPressed"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/buttonBorderColor"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="@color/buttonBackgroundPressed"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/buttonBorderColor"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="@color/buttonBackgroundNormal"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/buttonBorderColor"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Provide the color reference in `colors.xml`

Then assign the drawable to the button like this:

```
    <Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a custom button background drawable as below in your drawable folder

> button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        />
</selector>
```

> use this as background for your button in xml as below

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
/>
```

> your code as below

```
final Button signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //signIn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```